# Redirect S3 subfolder to another domain with Cloudfront

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cname

I have a static showcase website hosted on S3 and using CloudFront, and an online shop (Prestashop) and a blog (Wordpress), both hosted on OVH servers.

I want to make a hidden redirection on two subfolders of my static website so it acts like my 3 websites are on the same host, using the following pattern :

- mysite.com/ --> normal behaviour
- mysite.com/blog/ --> myblog.com/
- mysite.com/store/ --> mystore.com/

Of course, I need every request to be handled that way, eventually having something like that :

**mysite.com/store**/fr/1-myproduct.html

returns what

**mystore.com**/fr/1-myproduct.html

would have returned.

This seems really tricky, since I've found no real solution to my problem, and at this point I doubt it may even be possible to do such a thing.
I considered using a proxy but wouldn't that be like using a sledgehammer to get rid of a fly ?

I have searched for any possible redirection and I was only able to find subdomain/domain redirections...

So my question would be **"How can I do that ?"**
But right now I'm wondering **"Can one do that ?"**

---

P.S : It's my first post ever, I'm used to search for a long time before posting and I always end up finding a solution, except for now. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I don't think you can exactly what you want without reverse proxy. but you could manage A record to forward to the right server, you could have store.mysite.com and blog.mysite.com forward to ovh server

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Yes, that's what I wanted to do, and that's actually feasible, but my stakeholders absolutely want it in a subfolder-like for SEO purposes. Thank you for your answer though, I'll check about proxies since it's my last hope (how dramatic).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'll check about proxies since it's my last hope

Wait.

> I have a static showcase website hosted on S3 and using CloudFront

**CloudFront is a reverse proxy**.

Depending on how much flexibility you have with the other two sites, CloudFront can potentially take you where you want to go, combining multiple independent sites under one hostname.

This is done by creating additional origin servers for your distributions and then creating additional cache behaviors, with path patterns matching the additonal paths, such as `/blog` and `/blog/*` that send requests to the alternate origins.

There is, however, a catch.  CloudFront can't remove the matched pattern, so mainsite.example.com/blog/hello-world, matching the pattern `/blog/*` will be forwarded to blog.example.com/blog/hello-world -- not to blog.example.com/hello-world.¹  This will require changes to the other sites in order to integrate them in this way.

Unless...

If you already have unique path patterns, no problem, but if the extra sites' content is in the root of each individual site, you see the issue, here.  Not insurmoubtable, but still an issue.

<strike>Your only alternative will be a reverse proxy *behind* CloudFront to rewrite those paths and send the requests on to the alternate servers.  Truly not a big deal either, since HAProxy, Nginx, and Varnish all offer such functionality and can handle a large number of proxied requests on surprisingly small hardware.</strike>

The recently (2017) released [Lambda@Edge](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html) service allows you to rewrite paths on the fly, as requests are processed, if necessary.

But the bottom line is that the reason you have not found a real solution other than a proxy is that there is no alternative -- every path at a given hostname must be handled in one logical place -- one group of one or more identically-configured endpoints.  In the case of CloudFront, the logical place is physically distributed globally.

---

¹ CloudFront, natively, can actually prepend onto the path before forwarding the request, so requests for mainsite.example.com/bar/fizz can be forwarded to foosite.example.com/foo/bar/fizz by setting the origin path to `/foo` when you configure the origin.  But it can't remove path parts or otherwise modify the path without also using Lambda@Edge.  In the scenario discussed above, you would leave the origin path blank when configuring the additional origin servers.

Comment: Alright so I'm documenting on how I can do that, thanks for enlightening me, actually I started working on the website after it was deployed so I didn't see Cloudfront this way (I thought it was only a "website cacher").
However after I've set an origin domain (myblog.com) and a behaviour (/blog/* redirects everything to the custom origin myblog.com), I still get a 404 error and it uses my javascript to redirect me.
Is it possible that the redirection gets overridden by the error ?

Comment: To answer my previous commentary :
Yes !
If you have configured your Cloudfront distribution's 404 error to be redirected, any 404 error, whether it is on the distant origin or the base origin, will redirect to the same link you have set.
I have tried with an index.html file in myblog.com/blog and without it.
With it, it displays correctly the content, and without it goes back to the 404 page I've set on my base origin, and therefore, overrides the wordpress' 404 page.

Comment: Heads up!  As of 2017-07-17, the issue described in footnote 1 has a native solution in Lambda@Edge, which allows you to execute custom Node.js code inside CloudFront to tweak the request URI as needed.  If you are reading this in the future, ping me to come back and add that new information.

Answer (score 1):

Single S3 bucket with the following behavior :

domain.com-> serves the files from root of bucket

domain.com/blog -> serves the files from subfolder in S3 bucket (this is not default behavior)

**How to :**

https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/compute/implementing-default-directory-indexes-in-amazon-s3-backed-amazon-cloudfront-origins-using-lambdaedge/

**Lambda edge code:**

'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

```
// Extract the request from the CloudFront event that is sent to Lambda@Edge 
var request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

// Extract the URI from the request
var olduri = request.uri;

// Match any '/' that occurs at the end of a URI. Replace it with a default index
var newuri = olduri.replace(/\/$/, '\/index.html');

// Log the URI as received by CloudFront and the new URI to be used to fetch from origin
console.log("Old URI: " + olduri);
console.log("New URI: " + newuri);

// Replace the received URI with the URI that includes the index page
request.uri = newuri;

// Return to CloudFront
return callback(null, request);
```

};

**Summary of code higher :**

- lambda edge rewrites the path "/blog/" to "/blog/index.html"