# Honey tokens using AWS API Gateway and Lambda functions

Tags: security, dns, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, brute-force

I want to setup fake URLs or honeytoken to trick an attacker to follow those links, and have a script to auto block the attacker IPs using AWS WAF.

Security is a big thing these days, and our web infrastructure has already been a target of massive bruteforce and DDOS attempts. I want to setup tracks so attacker who are using directory traversing attacks can be found. e.g A common directory listing attacks traverse URLs like ../admin, ../wp-admin etc while scanning a target website. I want to setup a mechanism to get alerted when any of these non-existent URLs get browsed.

Question:
1. Is it possible to redirect part of web-traffic e.g www.abc.com/admin to API gateway and remaining www.abc.com to my existent servers?
2. How will I setup DNS entries for such, if it is possible?
3. Is there a different/easy to achieve this.

Any suggestion is welcome, as I am open to Ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can first setup a Cloudfront distribution with WAF ip blacklisting. Then setup a honey pot using API Gateway and Lambda which becomes a origin for urls like /admin, /wp-admin.

Following example with [bad bot blocking using honeypots](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-waf-sample/tree/master/waf-bad-bot-blocking) can provide you with a head start.

Comment: @ahsan, Thanks for your suggestion. I am already using a [honeypot](https://github.com/0x4D31/honeyLambda) for this and it works fine. The part I am confused about is how I will route the traffic to my API gateway. 
As I explained in my question the way dns works www.abc.com will always land on my server (say x.x.x.x) how can I make www.abc.com/admin a sub-resource to land on API gateway. I hope this is clear now.

Thanks

Comment: You mean for bots to call honeypot link?

Comment: Yes, because normally if a bot scrap for www.abc.com/admin it will get a 404 since my server is not serving this page. But I want this to land on API gateway from where I can route it to lambda and block the IP.

Comment: Readme of example link tells https://github.com/awslabs/aws-waf-sample/tree/master/waf-bad-bot-blocking to include it as a hidden link in a webpage but not include it in the robots.txt file

Comment: Yeah, including it in a url as hidden link is one solution, but this will only work if I actually serve www.abc.com/admin page. In my scenario there is no /admin page. I want www.abc.com/admin and other interesting URLs to be served through API gateway. This is more of a routing question.Thanks for your suggestions so far.

Comment: You can put API gateway web page servings behind CloudFront origin right?

Comment: Yes, can you explain this a bit.

Comment: Your entire site points to the CloudFront distribution (in DNS), which acts as a globally-distributed reverse proxy, routing each request to different destinationsl servers based on path matching.  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38709097/1695906).