# Route 53 DNS: Different DNS for base URL and endpoints (test.co and test.co/api)

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

Hopefully you all can help - we're looking to migrate our website from an EC2 instance to Webflow hosting. Unfortunately, we'd like to keep our API on the EC2 instance. Is it possible (in DNS in general, and specifically with route53) to have one DNS record for test.co and it's URL's (text.co/zxc, test.co/abc) and one DNS record specifically for the API URLs (test.co/api/abc)?

This would make the process much, much easier, as we wouldn't have to migrate the files to our EC2 instance and could keep the benefits of hosting on Webflow. However, performance is a key concern here for the API layer - my gut tells me that redirects are slow, and would add time to every API call. Not ideal.

Let me know what you think - cheers!

Comment: You can point your DNS to a CloudFront distribution, and then define the EC2 instance and the new web site as origin servers, routing `/api*` to the API and everything else to the web site.   CloudFront is marketed as a CDN but is in fact a globally-distributed reverse proxy that can accomplish exactly what you want, as I described [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38709097/1695906).  Unlike redirects, this can make everything faster, not slower, even without caching, because it also optimizes the network path from the browser to you.

Answer (score 1):

Using Route53 (or any DNS host) you can only resolve the hostname part (not the path) of the URL to your EC2 instance (E.g test.co, text.co) using either using.

- CName mapping to the Domain Name assigned to the EC2 instance
- A Record to the IP of the EC2 instance

Note: It is recommended to setup an Elastic IP for the EC2 instance if you directly map the EC2 instance to Route53.

You need to map /zxc /abc and /api/abc paths to relevant routes inside your EC2 instance either at WebServer level or using a proxy (E.g Nginx, Apache).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible (in DNS in general, and specifically with route53) to
> have one DNS record for test.co and it's URL's (text.co/zxc,
> test.co/abc) and one DNS record specifically for the API URLs
> (test.co/api/abc)?

The best solution is to create a subdomain. api.test.com, then create an "A" record that point your api.test.com to your EC2 instance.

#### NJOY